# Inline-block element inside inline element doen't affect outer's height

Tags: html, css

I am making a page about japanese, with some furiganas (reading annotations). For aesthetic reason, these furiganas are hand-made, not `<ruby>` tags.

When I add a styled span to them, the span cannot enclose the furigana correctly.

[image: example]

Simplified code:

```css
span.inline {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime; 
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p lang="ja">
<span class="inline">なんと<span class="inline-block">美</span>しい</span>
</p>
```

What I want (but without the ugly fix):

```css
span.inline {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 1em; /* ugly fix */
}

span.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime; 
  padding-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p lang="ja">
<span class="inline">なんと<span class="inline-block">美</span>しい</span>
</p>
```

Also, I want the element to wrap normally, and mix with other text nicely:

[image: desired]

Comment: inline elements can't have their height increased. Is it not possible to use inline-block instead?

Comment: Why do you not use  `<p class="inline">` instead of `<span class="inline">` and update the class to `p.inline`

Comment: @Asmoth In the `<p>` I have: `なんと美しい` this sentence blablabla...

Comment: @Ki I want them to wrap normally...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to for the element to wrap and have it's dimensions manipulated with CSS using current rendering engines.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by passing `inline-block` to the span.inline itself. Hope that is what you expected.

```css
span.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

span.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime; 
}
```

```html
<p lang="ja">
<span class="inline">なんと<span class="inline-block">美</span>しい</span>
</p>
```

Comment: `inline-flex` doesn't look like normal inline elements.

Comment: Okay got it. You want to achieve this using inline styling only. Right?

Comment: don't know what 'inline styling' mean... I updated my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it again if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `inline-block`, but it doesn't wrap. Maybe I should forget wrapping...?